# how to choose alt-f2 responder?

Tags: gnome, kde, krunner

I have a 22.04 Ubuntu (but the problem existed in earlied versions). From time to time "somthing" changes the application that shows up when I press alt+f2 from default Gnome do to Krunner.  After computer restart Gnome default alt-f2 window shows up, but after several hours it gets changed to krunner - I wasn't able to figure out what is responsible.

I have installed KDE Connect, which installed kde-plasma which created this issue I suppose.

How should I proceed to get rid of krunner randomly taking over Gnome desktop?